# Как получить цифру битового представления числа на определенной позиции?

Tags: php, mysql

Припустим есть  число 101101.Как определить цифру на опреденной позиции?
Думаю сдесь нужны сдвиги.
Интересует вариант PHP и Myqsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим в [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php) и пишем:

```
$bit = ($value >> $bitnumber) & 1;
```

По аналогии делается в [MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Bit_functions.html).

Comment: Спасибо.Работает.Прокоментирую,может для других будет понятно...
$bitnumber -номер позиции (нумерация идет с нуля)

Comment: @koza4ok: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

думаю лучше всего работать со строкой, а для этого число надо перевести в строковое представление битов.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php
Функция которая делает с числа 101010 и т.д. а тут уже обычная строковая операция.
перевернуть строку
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php
И тут уже просто получается строка в которой индекс соответсвует биту. И думаю вы уже разберетесь если интересно. Ну и собственно на затравку http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php
разбить строку на массив.

Comment: Тоже полезно знать....Спасибо